# Chrome Slow on Local IIS Sites

Tags: google-chrome, iis, localhost

I've seen this problem reported by other people whereby Chrome is incredibly slow to respond on local sites hosted in IIS. This is whether I'm using localhost or a specific host file entry (like mysite.local).

Existing fixes suggest removing the IPV6 entries from the host file, but that doesn't sort it out on my machine.

I'm running windows 8.1, vs2013 and IIS 8.5.

Can anyone help - its driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Its now driving me crazy!

Comment: No...still getting the issue...so annoying

Comment: I have the same issue. Been trying different things in chrome://flags without any luck

Comment: I've tried a lot of things too with no luck - very, very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

open 'worker processes' in features view of IIS panel and see if an earlier request is holding up rest of the queue. This can occur if the previous process waits for I/O to complete for instance.